# why the class margin not work?

Tags: css

The code is as below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div><span>shanghai</span><span class="margin"> </span><span>male</span></div>
</body>
</html>

.margin {
    width:40px;
    height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't give it a width because it is an inline element.

> This property specifies the content
>   width of boxes generated by
>   block-level and replaced elements. 
>   This property does not apply to
>   non-replaced inline-level elements.
>   -- [CSS 2.1 Width property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-width)

You can fix this by making it a block or inline-block element instead:

```
display:inline-block
```

However, this may not be supported by some browsers.  You can probably achieve the same result with this, however:

```
margin-left:40px
```

Comment: inline-block works on spans in IE - see http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html. FF2 is still less than happy with inline-block though

Answer (score 1):

CSS should go into the head section and should also be wrapped in < style > tags...

Unless you are accessing this value from a stylesheet. You would need to reference this in the head section of your document:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="RSS" href="MyStyleSheet.css">
```

Comment: sorry,I did,but omited in my post

Comment: the above code works in ie but not in firefox,do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

You should indicate that this is a CSS rule : [Ways to include CSS in your page](http://www.webstartcenter.com/howto/css_inc.php).

Comment: I see, but you put that rule outside the html doc, how can the browser know that this is a piece of CSS?!

Answer (score 0):

put

```
<style>
   .margin {    
     width:40px;    
     height:auto;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: Did you put it into a .html and see the effect?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing you class name maybe?

`margin` is an attribute. I'm not sure if CSS has reserved keywords though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the tag is empty. Just put "&nbsp;" between the two tags.